# How to update columns in another table from a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to update some columns in another table from a query result. I keep getting error. Please help.

```
Update customer_info
set customer_info.reader_ID     = aisle_info.reader_ID,
    customer_info.tag_no        = tag_logs.tag_no,
    customer_info.area          = aisle_info.area,
    customer_info.max_timestamp = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(tag_logs.timestamp),MAX(tag_logs.timestamp)) 

FROM tag_logs
INNER join aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID
WHERE T.tag_no = 515988190124;
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tag_logs

INNER join aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_I' at line 5

Comment: Its not clear what we are trying to achieve...  are we wanting to match *every* row in `tag_logs` ?   There are MIN() and MAX() aggregates, but no GROUP BY clause.  And `tag_no` in the WHERE clause is qualified with `T.` but `T` is not a valid identifier in the statement.  Multi-table UPDATE statement in MySQL does not have a `FROM` clause. Without a specification (illustrated by sample data and expected outcome), it's not possible to make a recommendation. We'd just guessing.

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(tag_logs.timestamp),MAX(tag_logs.timestamp)) 

FROM tag_logs
INNER join aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID
WHERE T.tag_no = 515988190124;  The answer of this entire formula should be update in customer_info columns reader id, tag_no, area and max timestamp.

Comment: The reference to `T.tag_no` is *invalid*. There is no `T` in the query. It's not a valid identifier. There is no criteria that matches rows from `tag_logs` or `aisle_info` to `customer_info`. Are we wanting to update a subset of rows (or every row) in `customer_info` with the same values? The MIN() and MAX() aggregates without a GROUP BY will collapse to a single row. My recommendation is to first write a SELECT statement that returns the rows to be updated, with the existing values of the columns, along with the new values to be assigned. Converting that to an UPDATE is straightforward.

Comment: SELECT aisle_info.reader_ID, tag_no, aisle_info.area, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp)) AS MAXTIME
FROM tag_logs INNER JOIN aisle_info ON tag_logs.reader_ID = aisle_info.reader_ID
WHERE tag_no = 515988190124;   I get a row of results for this. This query runs fine. Now the row that i get i want to update to another table but not from the first column, i want to insert these results from the third column onwards.

Comment: So, modify the `SELECT` statement to *include* the third table, the one you want to update. Given that the SELECT statement is returning a single row, due to the aggregate functions, I recommend using that as an inline view (derived table), wrap it in parens, and put in the `FROM` clause of an outer query, e.g.  `SELECT v.* FROM ( --query-- ) v`.  Then modify the query to perform a join operation to the target table e.g. `SELECT v.*, t.* FROM ( --query-- ) v JOIN target_table t ON ... WHERE ... ` include conditions in ON or WHERE clause to specify which rows to match ...

Comment: The specification is *unclear*. This question has provided no example data, and no sample of the expected outcome. Without a specification, it's not possible to make a  recommendation of the SQL that will achieve that result. And again, the goal here should be to first write a SELECT statement that returns 1) the set of rows from the target table that are to be updated, and along with each row, 2) the new values to be assigned. Once we have a properly constructed SELECT statement of that form, converting to an UPDATE is usually straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.  Different databases have slightly different syntax on updates from select/join.  Think of MySQL as a select statement, and use the alias of the primary table you are trying to update and then the SET clauses are after that.

So I first will start by writing the SELECT query by itself.

```
select
      CI.Tag_No,
      AI.Reader_ID,
      AI.Area,
      MIN( TL.TimeStamp ) MinTime,
      MAX( TL.TimeStamp ) MaxTime
   from
      customer_info CI
         join tag_logs TL
            CI.tag_no = TL.tag_no
            join aisle_info AI
               on TL.Reader_ID = Reader_ID
   WHERE 
      CI.tag_no = 515988190124
   group by
      CI.Tag_No,
      AI.Reader_ID,
      AI.Area
```

So this gives us the final results of what you want, and you can confirm it as needed.

Then apply your update such as

```
update Customer_Info CIUpd
   JOIN 
   ( select
          CI.Tag_No,
          AI.Reader_ID,
          AI.Area,
          MIN( TL.TimeStamp ) MinTime,
          MAX( TL.TimeStamp ) MaxTime
       from
          customer_info CI
             join tag_logs TL
                CI.tag_no = TL.tag_no
                join aisle_info AI
                   on TL.Reader_ID = Reader_ID
       WHERE 
          -- notice your filter is HERE for the one tag_no you want to update
          -- and will result with only this on TAG_NO set of values returned
          CI.tag_no = 515988190124
       group by
          CI.Tag_No,
          AI.Reader_ID,
          AI.Area ) FirstQuery
      -- the JOIN will ensure updating only on that one tag_no
      ON CIUpd.Tag_No = FirstQuery.Tag_No
   set
      CIUpd.Reader_ID = FirstQuery.Reader_ID,
      CIUpd.Area = FirstQuery.Area,
      CIUpd.Max_TimeStamp = TimeStampDiff( second, FirstQuery.MinTime, FirstQuery.MaxTime )
```

Now this is not a perfect answer as your original query was not a proper query using the MIN() / MAX() context.  When doing an aggregate query, you need to apply a group by on all NON aggregate columns.  In this case you did not clarify any such group consideration on the Reader_ID and Area which COULD result in multiple rows from your tag_logs and aisle_info tables.

If the aisle info will be the same all the time for a given Tag_No, then that's simple, just skip the grouping on that and change those column retrieve values as MAX() each.  if they never change, MAX() or even MIN() will always return the same value and not have an issue with the aggregate query without non-aggregate columns.

If you can provide additional clarification of data, purpose, etc, please edit your original post vs just leaving a comment.  Then leave a comment for me to please review with updated info.